# Como fazer Lista Guardar tudo do Usuário?

Tags: c#, classes, lista

Olá é minha primeira pegunta aqui, Gostaria de tirar uma dúvida.
Gostaria de criar uma List que guardasse o nome, e-mail, senha do usuário.
Alguém poderia me ajudar? Desde Já agradeço, Segue o código.

*Codigo Main*

```
class Program
{

    #region cor
    public static void Verde()
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    }
    public static void Azulm()
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
    }

    public static void Amarelo()
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;

    }

    public static void Preto()
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
    }
    public static void Azul()
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
    }
    public static void Vermelho()
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;

    }
    public static void Cinza()
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray;

    }
    #endregion
    public static void Fechar()
    {

        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)

    {
        for (;;)
        {
            //Pergunta Inicial "TEM CADASTRO?"
            Amarelo();
            Console.WriteLine("Você possui Cadastro? se sim Digite 1, se não 2");
            int c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            //Se o Usuário Nao Possuir Cadastro
            if (c == 2)
            {

                Console.Clear();
                Verde();
                Vermelho();

                Console.WriteLine("                           _______________________________ ");
                Console.WriteLine("                          |                               |");
                Console.WriteLine("                          |     BEM VINDO AO HelpTour     |");
                Console.WriteLine("                          |  _________________________    |");
                Verde();
                Console.WriteLine("                          |          |CADASTRO|           |");
                Vermelho();
                Console.WriteLine("                          |_______________________________|");
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                Console.Title = "Cadastro";
                Amarelo();
                Console.Write("Digite o nome de usuario desejado.:");
                Verde();
                string nomeA = Console.ReadLine();
                Amarelo();
                Console.Write("Digite a senha desejada.:");
                Verde();
                string senhaA = Console.ReadLine();
                Amarelo();
                Console.Write("Digite o email desejado.:");
                Verde();
                string emailA = Console.ReadLine();
                bool Vazio;
                if (nomeA == "" || senhaA == "" || nomeA == "")
                {
                    Vermelho();
                    Console.WriteLine("Error Empty, Fechando em 3 segundos.");
                    Vazio = true;
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                    Fechar();
                }


                //possui Cadastro



                #region Login
                if (c == 1)

                {

                    Vermelho();
                    Console.WriteLine("                           _______________________________ ");
                    Console.WriteLine("                          |                               |");
                    Console.WriteLine("                          |     BEM VINDO AO HelpTour     |");
                    Console.WriteLine("                          |  _________________________    |");
                    Verde();
                    Console.WriteLine("                          |           |LOGIN|             |");
                    Vermelho();
                    Console.WriteLine("                          |_______________________________|");
                    Console.WriteLine("\n");

                    Usuario usuario1 = new Usuario();

                    usuario1.nome = nomeA;
                    usuario1.senha = senhaA;
                    usuario1.email = emailA;
                    Amarelo();
                    Console.Write("Digite seu nome de usuario:");
                    Verde();
                    string nome = Console.ReadLine();

                    Amarelo();
                    Console.Write("Digite sua senha:");
                    Verde();
                    string senha = Console.ReadLine();
                    Amarelo();
                    Console.Write("Digite seu email:");
                    Verde();
                    string email = Console.ReadLine();

                    if (nome == "" || senha == "" || email == "")
                    {

                        Vermelho();
                        Console.WriteLine("Error Empty, Fechando em 3 segundos.");
                        Vazio = true;
                        Thread.Sleep(3000);
                        Fechar();

                    }

                    Console.Title = "HelpTour";

                    List<Usuario> UserCadastro = new List<Usuario>();
                    UserCadastro.Add(usuario1);




                    if (nome == nomeA && senha == senhaA && email == emailA) // IF Do Login(Se ele conseguir Logar)
                    {


                        Console.Clear();
                        Verde();
                        Console.WriteLine("Login Efetuado Com sucesso");
                        Amarelo();
                        Console.WriteLine("Seja bem-vindo");
                        Vermelho();
                        Console.WriteLine("                           _______________________________ ");
                        Console.WriteLine("                          |                               |");
                        Verde();
                        Console.WriteLine("                          |        Escolha um Local       |");
                        Vermelho();
                        Console.WriteLine("                          |  _________________________    |");
                        Console.WriteLine("                          |_______________________________|");
                        Console.WriteLine("\n");

                        Amarelo();
                        Console.WriteLine("\n 1-Marco zero ");
                        Console.WriteLine("\n 2-Porto de Galinhas ");
                        Console.WriteLine("\n 3-Praia de Boa Viagem");
                        Console.WriteLine("\n 4-Parque da Jaqueira  ");

                    }


                    else
                    {
                        Vermelho();
                        Console.WriteLine("Login ou senha errada.");

                    }



                    TelaInicial inicial = new TelaInicial();

                    inicial.localEscolhidopb = "Praia De Boa Viagem";
                    inicial.caminhoAteOLocalpb = "Via Av Boa Viagem";
                    inicial.distanciaDoLocalpb = 5;

                    Locais locais = new Locais();
                    locais.Marcozero = 1;
                    locais.PortodeGalinhas = 2;
                    locais.PraiadeBoaViagem = 3;
                    locais.ParquedaJaqueira = 4;

                    int lug = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    int fd;
                    Usuario FeedBack = new Usuario();

                    FeedBack.feedbacks = 1;
                    FeedBack.feedbackn = 2;

                    if (lug == 1)
                    {


                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.Title = inicial.localEscolhidoM;
                        Console.WriteLine(inicial.caminhoAteOLocalM);
                        Verde();
                        Console.WriteLine(inicial.distanciaDoLocalM + "KM" + (", Neste Local há Varias Atividades Pela Cidade, Varios lugares de Compras e lugares historicos para ser visitado!"));
                        Azulm();
                        Console.WriteLine("Gostou do HelpTuor? Digite 1 para GOSTEI e 2 para NAO GOSTEI!");
                        Verde();
                        fd = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        Amarelo();
                        Verde();


                        if (fd == 1)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Obrigado Pela Colaboração :Você VOTOU Sim");
                        }
                        if (fd == 2)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Obrigado Pela Colaboração :Você VOTOU Não");

                        }
                        if (fd != 2 && fd != 1)
                        {
                            Vermelho();
                            Console.WriteLine("Invalido");
                        }


                    }

                    if (lug == 2)
                    {


                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.Title = inicial.localEscolhidopg;
                        Console.WriteLine(inicial.caminhoAteOLocalpg);
                        Verde();
                        Console.WriteLine(inicial.distanciaDoLocalpg + "KM" + (", Neste Local há varias Praias, Restaurantes de Comida Tipica e Animais Marinhos, Para serem Degustados ou Observados."));
                        Azulm();
                        Console.WriteLine("Gostou do HelpTuor? Digite 1 para GOSTEI e 2 para NAO GOSTEI!");
                        fd = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        Amarelo();
                        Verde();

                        if (fd == 1)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Obrigado Pela Colaboração :Você VOTOU Sim");
                        }
                        if (fd == 2)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Obrigado Pela Colaboração :Você VOTOU Não");

                        }
                        if (fd != 2 && fd != 1)
                        {
                            Vermelho();
                            Console.WriteLine("Invalido");
                        }

                    }

                    if (lug == 3)
                    {


                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.Title = inicial.localEscolhidopb;
                        Console.WriteLine(inicial.caminhoAteOLocalpb);
                        Verde();
                        Console.WriteLine(inicial.distanciaDoLocalpb + "KM" + (", Neste Local Há Praia (Cuidado Com os Tubarões e Trombadinhas), Restaurantes, Parque Dona Lindu que tem varias atividades para ser feitas."));
                        Azulm();
                        Console.WriteLine("Gostou do HelpTuor? Digite 1 para GOSTEI e 2 para NAO GOSTEI!");
                        fd = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        Amarelo();
                        Verde();
                        if (fd == 1)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Obrigado Pela Colaboração :Você VOTOU Sim");
                        }
                        if (fd == 2)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Obrigado Pela Colaboração :Você VOTOU Não");

                        }
                        if (fd != 2 && fd != 1)
                        {
                            Vermelho();
                            Console.WriteLine("Invalido");
                        }
                    }

                    if (lug == 4)
                    {


                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.Title = inicial.localEscolhidopq;
                        Console.WriteLine(inicial.caminhoAteOLocalpq);
                        Verde();
                        Console.WriteLine(inicial.distanciaDoLocalpq + "KM" + (", No Parque da Jaqueira há atividades para as crianças e para os adultos, Tem pista de skate, Pista de Corrida, Brinquedos (Balanço,Gangorra, etc) E nas proximidades existência de Restaurantes."));
                        Azulm();
                        Console.WriteLine("Gostou do HelpTuor? Digite 1 para GOSTEI e 2 para NAO GOSTEI!");
                        fd = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        Amarelo();
                        Verde();
                        if (fd == 1)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Obrigado Pela Colaboração :Você VOTOU Sim");
                        }
                        if (fd == 2)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Obrigado Pela Colaboração :Você VOTOU Não");

                        }
                        if (fd != 2 && fd != 1)
                        {
                            Vermelho();
                            Console.WriteLine("Invalido");
                        }
                    }

                }

                Console.ReadKey();

                #endregion

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

*Classe usuario*

```
class Usuario
{
  public   string nome;
   public string senha;
     public string email;
    public int feedbacks;
    public int feedbackn;
    public void Login()
    {
        nome = "";
        senha = "";
        email = "";
    }
    public void Feed()
    {
        feedbacks=  0;
        feedbackn = 0;

    }

    public string Nome
    {
        get
        {
            return nome;
        }

        set
        {
            nome = value;

        }
    }

    public string Senha
    {
        get
        {
            return senha;
        }
        set
        {
            senha = value;
        }

    }
    public string Email
    {
        get
        {
            return email;
        }

        set
        {
            email = value;

        }

    }
    public int FeedN
    {
        get
        {
            return feedbackn;
        }

        set
        {
            feedbackn = value;

        }
    }
    public int FeedS
    {
        get
        {
            return feedbacks;
        }

        set
        {
            feedbacks = value;

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Essa pergunta está muito ampla, tente avançar um pouco mais na sua implementação e trazer uma questão mais específica.

Comment: @MarcellAlves Não é ampla kkk, é objetiva aliás, ele quer criar uma lista de usuários.

Comment: Pedro, você já cria uma lista de usuários (o nome é `UserCadastro`). Qual é a sua dúvida específica?

Comment: @LINQ acho que ele quer saber como armazena essa lista, basicamente a função de um DB.

Comment: Os comentários acima mostram que a pergunta não deixou claro o problema que o @pedro-henrique está tentando resolver.

Comment: Exatamente, @MarcellAlves. Eu já deixei meu voto pra fechar.

Comment: Teria como usar com Get Set? Ainda nao sei muito sobre Data Bank

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Existe as consultas Linq que fazem manipulação de informações dentro de coleções. Caso você queira adicionar apenas essas três propriedades ao invés de um objeto inteiro, ficaria algo como:

```
suaLista.Add(new Usuario
{
    Nome = "Gabriel",
    Email = "gabriel.gabriel@gabriel.com",
    Senha = "123Mudar"
});
```

No seu caso, aparentemente você esta fazendo um Console.Readline() do que o usuário insere e tenta adicionar dentro da lista, ficaria algo como:

```
string nome = Console.ReadLine();
string senha = Console.ReadLine();
string email = Console.ReadLine();
UserCadastro.Add(new Usuario
{
    Nome = nome ,
    Email = senha ,
    Senha = email 
});
```

O que você fez é criar um novo usuário e ao mesmo tempo eu falo quais os valores ele vai ser instanciado.

Para mais informações de manipulação de coleções:
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries

Comment: Consegui Obrigado!